# How do I disable audio sink suspend on idle using WirePlumber in Fedora 35 so that audio isn't delayed when starting playback?

Tags: linux, fedora, audio, pipewire

In Fedora 35, WirePlumber has replaced pipewire-media-session as the audio session manager. There is a highly annoying problem with audio on many built-in soundcards on Linux where the audio sink is suspended after nothing is played for 3 seconds. Upon resuming playback after 3 seconds have passed, audio is delayed or pops in. How do we fix this default behavior?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The relevant configuration file is `/usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua`, but don't edit the system version of it!

You need to copy it into `/etc/wireplumber/main.lua.d/` (global config) or `~/.config/wireplumber/main.lua.d/` (user config) and make the necessary changes.

The easiest way is to copy it into the global config location so that it applies to all user accounts:

```
sudo cp -a /usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua /etc/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua
sudo nano /etc/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua
```

You then need to scroll down to the bottom of the file, inside the `apply_properties` section, and add a line there which says:

```
["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"] = 0
```

I've done a lot more changes and customized it for my own personal hardware. Here's my configuration for reference, but this config is only useful for my exact devices. You actually only need the line above to disable the auto-suspend. Add it to your own default config. **Do not copy my config.** The other changes I've made are unrelated.

```
alsa_monitor.properties = {
  ["alsa.jack-device"] = true,
  ["alsa.reserve"] = true,
  ["alsa.midi.monitoring"] = true
}

alsa_monitor.rules = {
{
    matches = {
      {
        { "device.name", "matches", "alsa_card.*" }
      }
    },
    apply_properties = {
      ["api.alsa.use-acp"] = true,
      ["api.acp.auto-profile"] = false,
      ["api.acp.auto-port"] = false
    }
  },
  {
    matches = {
      {
        { "node.name", "matches", "alsa_output.pci-0000_0c_00.4.iec958-ac3-surround-51" }
      }
    },
    apply_properties = {
      ["api.alsa.period-size"] = 128,
      ["api.alsa.headroom"] = 2048,
      ["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"] = 0
    }
  },
  { 
    matches = {
      {
        { "node.name", "matches", "alsa_input.usb-BEHRINGER_UMC202HD_192k-00.analog-mono" }
      }
    },
    apply_properties = {
      ["api.alsa.period-size"] = 128
    }
  }
}
```

Setting the `session.suspend-timeout-seconds` property to `0` prevents the suspension/sleep behavior. It completely disables the behavior, as can be seen in WirePlumber's source code.

WirePlumber has to be restarted in order for changes to take effect:

```
systemctl --user restart wireplumber
```

Answer (score 2):

This is normally fixed in systems running PipeWire without WirePlumber that use pipewire-media-session by changing `session.suspend-timeout-seconds` to 0 in the bottom section of `/etc/pipewire/media-session.d/alsa-monitor.conf`. However, this directory or any session monitor configuration file is not found within Fedora 35 installations. There is virtually no documentation showing how to prevent sinks from suspending in 3 seconds, so I had to figure this one out by myself. Instead, we have to modify a Lua script within a script directory for WirePlumber. Navigate to `/usr/share/wireplumber/scripts/` and make a backup copy of `suspend-node.lua`. Then open `suspend-node.lua` in a text editor or the terminal using sudo privileges, and comment out the code block that is responsible for sink timeout and suspending sinks, so that the file looks like the following:

```
-- WirePlumber
--
-- Copyright © 2021 Collabora Ltd.
--    @author George Kiagiadakis <george.kiagiadakis@collabora.com>
--
-- SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

om = ObjectManager {
  Interest { type = "node",
    Constraint { "media.class", "matches", "Audio/*" }
  },
  Interest { type = "node",
    Constraint { "media.class", "matches", "Video/*" }
  },
}

sources = {}

om:connect("object-added", function (om, node)
  node:connect("state-changed", function (node, old_state, cur_state)
    -- Always clear the current source if any
    local id = node["bound-id"]
    if sources[id] then
      sources[id]:destroy()
      sources[id] = nil
    end

--    -- Add a timeout source if idle for at least 3 seconds
--    if cur_state == "idle" then
--      -- honor "session.suspend-timeout-seconds" if specified
--      local timeout =
--          tonumber(node.properties["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"]) or 3

--      if timeout == 0 then
--        return
--      end

--      -- add idle timeout; multiply by 1000, timeout_add() expects ms
--      sources[id] = Core.timeout_add(timeout * 1000, function()
--        -- Suspend the node
--        Log.info(node, "was idle for a while; suspending ...")
--        node:send_command("Suspend")

--        -- Unref the source
--        sources[id] = nil

--        -- false (== G_SOURCE_REMOVE) destroys the source so that this
--        -- function does not get fired again after 3 seconds
--        return false
--      end)
--    end

  end)
end)

om:activate()
```

There may be a better way to do this than commenting out the whole block, but at least this way processing time isn't wasted checking if the state of the sink is idle. Now, there's no annoying audio delay or pop when resuming playback of music and videos after the sink has been idle for several seconds. I hope this was helpful to those people using WirePlumber on Fedora 35.

Answer (score 2):

I've spent a lot of time googling and doing the things described here.

#### I'll just leave the whole algorithm here (works like a charm on Ubuntu 23.04)

1. Move configs to a global scope and change their `session.suspend-timeout-seconds` parameter:

   ```bash
   # Main config
    sudo mkdir -p /etc/wireplumber/main.lua.d
    sudo cp -a /usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua /etc/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua

    # Bluetooth config
    sudo mkdir -p /etc/wireplumber/bluetooth.lua.d/
    sudo cp -a /usr/share/wireplumber/bluetooth.lua.d/50-bluez-config.lua /etc/wireplumber/bluetooth.lua.d/50-bluez-config.lua

    # Change the needed settings in both config files
    # Pay attention to `--` in the beggining. It's a line comment in Lua. And we must remove it
    sudo sed -i 's/--\["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"\] = 5/\["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"\] = 0/g' /etc/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua
    sudo sed -i 's/--\["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"\] = 5/\["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"\] = 0/g' /etc/wireplumber/bluetooth.lua.d/50-bluez-config.lua
   ```
2. Then reload the services:

   ```bash
   systemctl --user restart pipewire wireplumber
   ```
3. Then you can test the status of all your audio devices by this command while playing and stopping the audio and then watching for status change:

   ```bash
   watch -cd -n .1 pactl list short sinks
   ```

   It shows statuses:

   - RUNNING — device is currently playing or it's been less than 10 seconds after previous playback
   - **IDLE — device is not playing but readly to play immidiately (what's needed!)**
   - SUSPEND — in this state the device will wake up with a delay (NOT needed)

   There must be no SUSPENDED statuses anymore after the first playback in session.

##### Congratulations! Now your audio will play seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of duplicating the existing (and pretty long) `50-alsa-config.lua` file, I suggest creating a much shorter file.

Here is my `~/.config/wireplumber/main.lua.d/51-alsa-custom.lua`:

```
rule = {
  matches = {
    {
      { "node.nick", "matches", "ALC887-VD Analog" },
    },
  },
  apply_properties = {
      ["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"] = 0
  },
}
table.insert(alsa_monitor.rules,rule)
```

I got the `node.nick` with the following command:

```
$ pactl list sinks |grep node.nick
                node.nick = "ALC887-VD Analog"
```

After this, you still need to restart the service:

`systemctl --user restart wireplumber`

Answer (score 1):

> The relevant configuration file is /usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua, but don't edit the system version of it

This solution does not work for bluetooth devices. To make it work copy the bluetooth file and change the property `session.suspend-timeout-seconds`.

```
sudo cp -a /usr/share/wireplumber/bluetooth.lua.d/50-bluez-config.lua /etc/wireplumber/bluetooth.lua.d/50-bluez-config.lua

sudo vi /etc/wireplumber/bluetooth.lua.d/50-bluez-config.lua
```

50-bluez-config.lua:

```
apply_properties = {
  --["node.nick"] = "My Node",
  --["priority.driver"] = 100,
  --["priority.session"] = 100,
  --["node.pause-on-idle"] = false,
  --["resample.quality"] = 4,
  --["channelmix.normalize"] = false,
  --["channelmix.mix-lfe"] = false,
  ["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"] = 0,  -- 0 disables suspend
  --["monitor.channel-volumes"] = false,

  -- Media source role, "input" or "playback"
  -- Defaults to "playback", playing stream to speakers
  -- Set to "input" to use as an input for apps
  --["bluez5.media-source-role"] = "input",
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the file `~/.config/wireplumber/main.lua.d/51-disable-suspension.lua`
and paste this in it:

```lua
table.insert (alsa_monitor.rules, {
  matches = {
    {
      -- Matches all sources.
      { "node.name", "matches", "alsa_input.*" },
    },
    {
      -- Matches all sinks.
      { "node.name", "matches", "alsa_output.*" },
    },
  },
  apply_properties = {
    ["session.suspend-timeout-seconds"] = 0,  -- 0 disables suspend
  },
})
```

Then restart WirePlumber:

```shell
systemctl --user restart wireplumber
```

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#Noticeable_audio_delay_or_audible_pop/crack_when_starting_playback